# why java executed comments line?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I'm using Java on Netbeans app. I have a method I couldn't solve it and aafter a lot of tring the compiler become run comments line. How can I solve that? I did debug, clean and build but nothing happen. I can't execute well anymore.

```
int size = 1 ;
String Continu = "Yes", courseID [] = new String [size] , lecturerID [] = new String [size] ;

public void addCourse() {
    try{
        if (Continu.equals("Yes") || Continu.equals("yes")){
            for (int i = 0; i<= size; i++){
                System.out.println("Enter Course ID to add: ");
                this.courseID[i] = in.next();
                System.out.println("Enter lecturer ID to add: ");
                this.lecturerID[i] = in.next();
                throw new Exception ("Error inside adding loop");
            } //for
        } //if
        else
            throw new Exception ("Else statment");
        //System.out.print("Do you want to add more course ID and lecturer ID ? 'Yes or No' ");
        //   Continu = in.nextLine(); 
            size ++; 
    } catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } // try - catch
    for(int i = 0; i<= this.courseID.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Course ID: " +this.courseID [i] +
                "Lecture ID: " +this.lecturerID[i]);
    } //for
} //addCourse
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: Java will never execute a comments line. Check if the code that is running is the code that you *think* is running. (If you change that string, you won't see the changed string when you run it)

Comment: @DavidKoelle Never say never! This commented line will execute `// \u000d System.out.println("This is the output generated from commented line");` as described in [How to execute Java code within Java comments](https://www.tothenew.com/blog/how-to-execute-java-code-within-java-comments/). Obviously that is not relevant for this question, but I mention it for completeness,

Comment: That is really interesting! Thanks for sharing! What I probably should have said instead was, "It is more likely that there is an error in how you're running the code than it is likely that there is an error in the Java compiler" but the idea that there could be a ghost Carraige Return character in the comment is interesting!